# How to simulate a fake keypress in C++

Tags: c++, windows, security

I want to make an anti-keylogger, and i tought of an idea, simulate a random fake keypress when the user inputs some text in a window.
Let's say, my application will simulate a fake keypress every time a key is pressed inside a Firefox, GoogleChrome window.

I already tried SendInput but it sends the character for real (it's not fake, the character is really printed, and that's not what i want).
I already have a function to generate a random character one time, but the problem is sending it as a fake key-press.

So the objective is, if the user is infected with any sort of keylogger, the keylogger will only receive the **fake generated characters** that i send, and **not** what the user is **really taping**.
My project will be mainly on Windows, console application and SMFL Gui, do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: Since a keylogger captures actual keys pressed how would you be able to send a "fake" key press that doesn't count as a key press and have it be captured?

Comment: First of all, this is platform specific. Second, fake key presses will most likely interfer with the user activities and have actual impact on whats going on, and finally, you can write a keylogger to capture texting events completely unrelated to the keyboard and is capable of capturing whats being written regardless of key events.

Comment: If the user is running two programs: `X` and `Y`, and both of them is accepting keyboard input, how would your program be able to decide which of them should get the real input and which should get the fake input? The point is: both `X` and `Y`, or one of them, or neither of them can be a keylogger.

Comment: How does the receiving program know which keypresses are fake and which are real? You've got a catch-22 here.

Comment: -Nathan, let's say it would be like a real keypress except for the special windows (Firefix and GoogleChrome in my example).
-Havenard, let's say it on Windows, i didn't really understand your example, but just closely.
-Gurka, let's say my program will only have a special list of processes that it will give the right keys to.
-Tadman, maybe by spaming the fake inputs to all the apps except the special app that will have the right input.

Comment: This concept is on pretty wobbly ground to start with. You'll need to get your hands on a few keyloggers of different types and experiment with what tricks them and what doesn't while also ensuring you don't confuse the target applications. I'm not sure you can do the second part.

Comment: Well yeah it will be really difficult to avoid tricking the target applications, but i think it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simulate keypresses on the Windows platform.

The Microsoft Windows platforms uses a messaging system.  When a key is pressed, the OS sends a message to listening tasks containing the *value* of the key that was pressed.

The MSDN website contains more details about how to send keypress messages.

Also, there are similar questions on StackOverflow.

Try these search terms:

- MSDN C++ keypress simulate
- MSDN C++ key press message
- MSDN Send key press message c++
- StackOverflow C++ key press simulate windows

**Edit 1:**
There are also methods to *hook* a listener to the keypress message.  For example, a Key Logger could sign up as the primary listener, receive the message, process the key, then *forward* the message on to other listeners.

If you want to bypass the Key Logger, you will have to dig deeper into *keyboard hooks* and understand how they work.

Comment: We are making a point here, a messaging system you say, that will be a starting point, i'll have a look at those.